# Range of valid character for a base 64 encoding

Tags: java, regex, base64, apache-commons

I am interested in the following:
Is there a list of characters that would **never** occur as part of a base 64 encoded string?
For example `*`. I am not sure if this would occur or not. If the original input actually had `*` as part of it would that be encoded differently?

Comment: I would look at this page to work it out. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: The notion that a `*` in the input would be represented as a `*` in the output indicates conceptual confusion about the relationship of the input to the output. A `*` could appear in the output if and only if it's a member of the base 64 character set ... regardless of what's in the input.

Answer (score 136):

Here is what I could turn up: [RFC 4648](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt)

It includes this convenient table:

```
                  Table 1: The Base 64 Alphabet

 Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding
     0 A            17 R            34 i            51 z
     1 B            18 S            35 j            52 0
     2 C            19 T            36 k            53 1
     3 D            20 U            37 l            54 2
     4 E            21 V            38 m            55 3
     5 F            22 W            39 n            56 4
     6 G            23 X            40 o            57 5
     7 H            24 Y            41 p            58 6
     8 I            25 Z            42 q            59 7
     9 J            26 a            43 r            60 8
    10 K            27 b            44 s            61 9
    11 L            28 c            45 t            62 +
    12 M            29 d            46 u            63 /
    13 N            30 e            47 v
    14 O            31 f            48 w         (pad) =
    15 P            32 g            49 x
    16 Q            33 h            50 y
```

So a regular expression that matches any character that should **never** appear in Base 64 encodings would be:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]
```

However, as kapeps answer points out, this is only the recommendation. Specific implementations might choose a different set of 64 characters. (In fact, even the linked RFC contains an alternative table for URL and filename safe encoding, which replaces character 62 and 63 with `-` and `_` respectively). So I guess it really depends on the implementation that created the encoding.

Comment: `/` being part of the standard means that this can't be used for naming files. Also, why not start with `0` before `A`? Why make the first ten numbers in the base system purposefully different?

Comment: I can't answer your second question, but the RFC does provide an alternative encoding that doesn't use `/` and `+` and is specifically designed to be safe for filenames and URLs.

Comment: @MartinEnder By the way, a more appropriate regular expression would be `^[A-Za-z0-9+/]+={0,2}$`.

Comment: Is there any python function which can return the value of the encoding ? for example, something like  base64('A') = 0, base64('O') = 14

Comment: @Praveen, no, because in base64 3 8-bit ASCII characters change into 4 6-bit base64 characters (24 total bits). The encoding of any character will depend on the character before or after it in the original string.

Comment: Why is it A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +/? Why not 0-9, A-Z, a-z, +/?

Comment: @user14628718 : there is a general rule of thumb to approach answers to this and similar questions: the world is far from being perfect ... it's YOU who can change it for better ,,, so decide for yourself what does make sense instead of trying to understand the motivation of others ( https://github.com/oOosys/oOo ),

Answer (score 26):

You are probably safe with the other answers in most situations, but according to the [Wikipedia article on Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Design) there shouldn't be a definite list you can rely on:

> The particular choice of character set selected for the 64 characters required for the base varies between implementations.

[RFC 4648](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt) mentions other alphabets, such as the *"URL and Filename safe" Base 64 Alphabet*, where `+` and `/` are replaced with `-` and `_`.

There's a [table of Base64 variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) which use different characters. 
Keep in mind that there are implementation specific rules about line separators, which you can find in the same table. Some implementations like [Mime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#MIME) even allow (and ignore) characters that are not in the alphabet.

Answer (score 25):

Base64 only contains `A–Z`, `a–z`, `0–9`, `+`, `/` and `=`. 
So the list of characters not to be used is: all possible characters minus the ones mentioned above.

For special purposes `.` and `_` are possible, too.

Comment: Is `=` included in standard base64? It looks like that brings the total number of characters to 65. What is your source for this?

edit: it looks like the `=` is for padding, in case data is complete before a frame is finished.

Comment: I have never seen a dot or underscore in Base64 data. What do you mean with "special purposes" ???? I would say this is definitely wrong.

Comment: @Elmue They got it a bit wrong, they meant a dash instead of a period. - and _ are allowed as alternatives to + and / in order to be usable for filenames and URLs.

Comment: I don't know what they might have meant. But this part of the answer is useless without any further explanation. I have never seen "special purposes" for Base64!

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Design

> MIME's Base64 implementation uses A–Z, a–z, and 0–9 for the first 62 values

So for the most part you should expect only alphanumeric characters. The example table in this article shows '+' and '-' also; it's unlikely you would see '*'.

You can use http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp to convert to Base64 for example, and for '*' this returns "Kg=="