# Different YouTube URLs points to the same video

Tags: url, youtube

I found some bug in youtube when I reverse engineering it's video id generator. If I change last characther of the video id, it redirects to same video. How is this possible?

Example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f2
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f3
```

But this url isn't work:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The videoId is 8 Bytes (64 bit) base64 encoded. From [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101153) :

> For the videoId, it is an 8-byte (64-bit) integer. Applying
>   Base64-encoding to 8 bytes of data requires 11 characters. However,
>   since each Base64 character conveys exactly 6 bits, this allocation
>   could actually hold up to 11 × 6 = 66 bits--a surplus of 2 bits over
>   what our payload needs. The excess bits are set to zero, which has the
>   effect of excluding certain characters from ever appearing in the last
>   position of the encoded string. In particular, the videoId will always
>   end with one of the following: { A, E, I, M, Q, U, Y, c, g, k, o, s,
>   w, 0, 4, 8 }

In your case, your videoId is `9bZkp7q19f0` :

```
enc.  | 9      b      Z      k      p      7      q      1      9      f      | 0
value | 61     27     25     36     41     59     42     53     61     31     | 52
bin.  | 111101 011011 011001 100100 101001 111011 101010 110101 111101 011111 | 1101  00
```

If you modify the last character, the 64 bit id will change if the 4 most significative bit (MSB) are modified :

9bZkp7q19f1 :

```
enc.  | 9      b      Z      k      p      7      q      1      9      f      | 1
value | 61     27     25     36     41     59     42     53     61     31     | 53
bin.  | 111101 011011 011001 100100 101001 111011 101010 110101 111101 011111 | 1101  01
```

9bZkp7q19f2 :

```
enc.  | 9      b      Z      k      p      7      q      1      9      f      | 2
value | 61     27     25     36     41     59     42     53     61     31     | 54
bin.  | 111101 011011 011001 100100 101001 111011 101010 110101 111101 011111 | 1101  10
```

9bZkp7q19f3 :

```
enc.  | 9      b      Z      k      p      7      q      1      9      f      | 3
value | 61     27     25     36     41     59     42     53     61     31     | 55
bin.  | 111101 011011 011001 100100 101001 111011 101010 110101 111101 011111 | 1101  11
```

This will give a different video id (note the 4 MSB of the last Byte are modified `1101` to `1110`) :

```
enc.  | 9      b      Z      k      p      7      q      1      9      f      | 4
value | 61     27     25     36     41     59     42     53     61     31     | 56
bin.  | 111101 011011 011001 100100 101001 111011 101010 110101 111101 011111 | 1110  00
```

`9bZkp7q19f4` will give a different 64 bit id. Note that if such an id exists `9bZkp7q19f4`, `9bZkp7q19f5`, `9bZkp7q19f6` and `9bZkp7q19f7` will give the same id.

You can check the base64 encoding/values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13195218/2614364)